# Multi-column mega menu dropdown?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, megamenu

I have UIX requirement to implement multi-column/mega drop downs.
Can somebody provide code, available jquery plugin, programming best practice/advice to achieve this UI functionality (yes I have googled and did not really see anything appealing?

**DISCLAIMER for editors:** This is a general ask. Not sure what "technical" criteria needs to be called out here but if you need more info please inquire about what I can include to make this helpful or less ambigous and I can edit my response (or feel free to edit please, thx!).

Comment: To assist answerers, please include specifics about which jQuery plugins you have tried, and why they didn't work for you.

Comment: I have tried http://www.sitepoint.com/make-a-mega-drop-down-menu-with-jquery/ and out of box was not appealing style-wise or for multi-col display.

Comment: @JaJ If the best you can say is "I didn't like the style," then I'm afraid you're asking for help from the wrong people. There are dozens of plugins you can find by googling "jquery dropdown"; I would start there and improve one of those if it doesn't quite meet your needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a few examples:

- http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu-plugin/getting-started/
- http://www.visibilityinherit.com/code/mega-drop-down.php
- http://codecanyon.net/item/css3-mega-drop-down-menu/126387

Answer (score 4):

You can also check the following free

1. [Css only megamenu dropdown tutorial](http://www.webgalli.com/blog/easily-create-a-mega-menu-dropdown-in-five-minutes/)
2. [Javascript megamenu dropdown](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/jkmegamenu.shtml)